# caching flv data in flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, caching, flv

I am developing an eLearning application in Flex which shows flv movies hosted on a webserver. If the app has many simultaneous users the download demand is quite high because a lot of users need to download the (same) movie(s). Is there a way I can precache this data in my flex client like storing it in the browsercache or something so that for later sessions the bandwidth demand is less high?

Thanks,
Martijn

Answer (score 1):

Browsers will naturally cache the flvs. Make sure you don't have no-cache headers set on the flvs. However, the cache can fill up, and nothing prevents users from clearing their browser cache.

A better solution in my opinion would be to host the flvs on something like [amazon cloud front](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).

---

**Edit** Also, you should consider moving from flv to h.264 as it has been supported since Flash Player 9 (version 9,0,115,0) Update 3 and has much better compression than flvs.

Comment: The problem is not so much my serverside capacity as it is the download capacity of my clients internet..so I dont think a CDN would help right??

Comment: @Gluip If the bottleneck is the client's bandwidth, simultaneous users shouldn't be any worse than individual users. (Unless the clients are on the same intranet.) And in that case, see my edit about h.264

Comment: What about mobile devices? I have some android users and they have very limited browser cache. Is there anyway to 'fix' that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that. Comment here if you find an answer.

Comment: After some more research I think I will go with a proxy webserver. See this post http://superuser.com/questions/334082/is-there-a-3g-router-with-local-caching